# carousel resizing

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have a working carousel but I am looking to resize the whole thing. I am able to resize the images but the next and previous buttons and the image indicator don't change and i can't figure out how to change these to match what ever the size of the images are.

```
<div id="homeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#homeCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Makita.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Metabo.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Bosch.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#homeCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  /* Make the image fully responsive */
  .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
  .carousel-item {
   height:450px
  }
   .carousel-item img{
   width:100%;
   height:100%;
   object-fit:cover
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Makita.png" alt="First slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Metabo.png" alt="Second slide">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="images/Bosch.png" alt="Third slide">
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi sorry for late reply, that works great for resizing the image, but the previous and next buttons change based on image size they stay the same as they were initially,  any ideas

Comment: You can try **carousel-item** fix height